# How often the cookie messages will be shown to users when they access office 365's sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, cache, cookie

We have one of our users deleted his browser cache. then when he access an Office 365 sharepoint site, where he got this cookie message:-

[image]

now i think since he deleted his browser cache, then his cookies got deleted, and as a result the above message got shown.
**But my question, is how often this message will be shown? could it be shown even if the browser cache was not deleted?** i did not find relevant info about this .. as some users got afraid of these messages, but at the same time i do not have any info if those message will be shown in the future? or those are a result of clearing the browser cache, and if the browser cache was not deleted those messages should not be shown?